# Getting MySQL installed

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded `mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86.tar.gz` from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=451505). Now I've got a folder full of MySQL-related files. Trouble is, I don't know what to do to install MySQL. I tried executing `mysql_install_db`, but the result was:

```
Last login: Sat May 24 10:45:08 on ttys000
host237-40-dynamic:~ michelegorini$ /Users/michelegorini/Downloads/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86/scripts/mysql_install_db ; exit;
FATAL ERROR: Could not find ./bin/my_print_defaults

If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.

If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location.

logout

[Process completed]
```

So what do I do now?

**Update:**
Taking the answer into account, I tried something, with this result:

```
Last login: Sat May 24 10:45:08 on ttys000
host237-40-dynamic:Hakka_ michelegorini$ $ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400
-bash: $: command not found
host237-40-dynamic:Hakka_ michelegorini$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)" && brew install git &&
> brew update
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400
-bash: brew: command not found
host237-40-dynamic:Hakka_ michelegorini$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)" && brew install git && brew update && brew install mysql
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400
-bash: brew: command not found
host237-40-dynamic:Hakka_ michelegorini$
```

What now?

Comment: What about "I have already done that with mac for linux, since I'm on mac, and ended up finding this archive"?

Comment: Read this: http://blog.ijun.org/2011/02/mysqlinstalldb-fatal-error-could-not.html

Comment: I tried `/usr/local/bin/mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local ` and got `FATAL ERROR: Could not find my-default.cnf

If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.

If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
pointing to that location.` But that `my_default.cnf` file is unfindable on my File System.

Comment: OK how stupid could I be? I looked for a file with an underscore when the missing file had a dash! Let me try again…

Comment: The file is now in `bin`, but the result is the same.

Comment: If I'd just gone one link further, I'd have found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOicYSxHlPc), which has now solved my problem, as far as I can tell. For further reading, in case one wants to interface SQL with Java, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oE4D7FmP2Lw) might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The homebrew package manager takes away the pain in installing packages on your computer.

[Here's how to install mysql on a mac](http://benjsicam.me/blog/how-to-install-mysql-on-mac-os-x-using-homebrew-tutorial/)

The command in one line:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)" && brew install git && brew update && brew install mysql
```

Comment: The result of that is Terminal gets stuck with `>`, and typing `brew update` at that point leads to `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400
-bash: brew: command not found`.